# Shared wireless network immediately disconnects

Tags: 11.10, wireless, drivers

I have an ethernet cable coming into my PC and I have a USB wireless adapter. I want to create a WiFi network that would use the wired connection's internet.

So I've added a new wireless network, but now it connects and immediately disconnects - I see "Connection established" then "Disconnected" and so on (I've set it to connect automatically).

The adapter I have is `Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8187 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. [RTL8187][1] Wireless Adapter`. The linked page contains some instructions, but I can't download the Win98 driver. Is that what I need to fix the problem?

Also, there are some interesting syslog entries:

```
Apr  3 22:54:01 r6 NetworkManager[1095]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 2
Apr  3 22:54:01 r6 wpa_supplicant[1351]: Trying to associate with SSID 'vxcvxcz'
Apr  3 22:54:03 r6 wpa_supplicant[1351]: nl80211: Failed to set interface into IBSS mode
Apr  3 22:54:03 r6 wpa_supplicant[1351]: Association request to the driver failed**
Apr  3 22:54:03 r6 wpa_supplicant[1351]: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:00:00:00:00:00 completed (reauth) [id=-1 id_str=]
Apr  3 22:54:03 r6 NetworkManager[1095]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> completed
Apr  3 22:54:03 r6 NetworkManager[1095]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'vxcvxcz'.
Apr  3 22:54:03 r6 NetworkManager[1095]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Apr  3 22:54:03 r6 NetworkManager[1095]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Apr  3 22:54:03 r6 NetworkManager[1095]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr  3 22:54:03 r6 NetworkManager[1095]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Get) scheduled...
Apr  3 22:54:03 r6 NetworkManager[1095]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Apr  3 22:54:03 r6 NetworkManager[1095]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Get) started...
Apr  3 22:54:03 r6 NetworkManager[1095]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) started...
Apr  3 22:54:03 r6 avahi-daemon[1085]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 10.42.43.1.
Apr  3 22:54:03 r6 dnsmasq[1339]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Apr  3 22:54:03 r6 avahi-daemon[1085]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Apr  3 22:54:03 r6 avahi-daemon[1085]: Registering new address record for 10.42.43.1 on wlan0.IPv4.
Apr  3 22:54:03 r6 dnsmasq[1339]: using nameserver 192.168.1.1#53
Apr  3 22:54:03 r6 kernel: [  688.265466] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

I had similar problem.

To fix this, I added the following three lines to the bottom of /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

```
blacklist bcma
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist brcmutil
```

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/863799/comments/3